# Some websites take extremely long to load and show stalled in network tab

Tags: windows, networking, browser, windows-11

Some websites are loading extremely slow. When I look at the Network tab in the browser devtools, it shows resources being stalled for a long time. A few examples of sites that I'm having issues with are: digitalocean.com, deliveroo.com and bitvavo.com. The problem occurs only on this desktop and not on others.

I am on Windows 11, which might have something to do with this, but I can't find anything online about these issues.

Things that I have tried:

- Different browsers: Chromium edge, chrome and firefox
- Incognito mode.
- Disabling adblock
- Disabling windows defender
- Restarted Router
- Restarted PC.

This is what the console shows in the browser:

[image: This is what the console shows in the browser]

This is what the console shows in the browser:

[image: This is what the network tab shows]

I don't know how to further debug this problem, so I'm hoping someone here has an idea.

Comment: Since Windows 11 is a work-in-progress, can you try another OS, whether in a virtual machine, or running from USB? If the sites load rapidly, that test would eliminate issues with the web sites themselves and with your ISP, pointing instead to Windows OS  If they're still slow, then it's the site or the connection.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you can ignore the many 404's on the .map files - these files are only requested when the developer console is opened, and it makes sense that many public sites don't provide them. They're used for debugging javascript files.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I have solved my problem by downloading the latest ethernet driver  26.4 from the intel website. Those on the asus website didn't do it for me.